How to fix Lutris PCSX2 runner errors: libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0 missing and Qt_6.5 not found
When I run the PCSX2 runner in Lutris I get this error in the console and PCSX2 doesn't launch:
PCSX2: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_baseu-3.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How do I get this libwx_baseu-3.0? Using Debian 12 with KDE. wxgtk3.2-1 is installed.
Update: it works after disabling "Disable Lutris Runtime" in the runner options for PCSX2.
Update: Maybe that was because I had PCSX2 installed so after it's working again I tried removing that with sudo dpkg --remove PCSX2 but it still shows this error when reenabling the aforementioned option. This filename search in Debian12 shows that the library is contained in libwxbase3.2-1 (which I have installed) but it's at version 3.2.so.0 there. I then tried uninstalling the runner, restarting lutris, then reinstalling the pcsx2 runner. It again doesn't launch if the aforementioned option is not disabled but now with error /tmp/.mount_[uid]/usr/bin/pcsx2-qt: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt6Core.so.6: version 'Qt_6.5' not found (required by /tmp/.mount_[uid]/usr/bin/pcsx2-qt). When I disable the option again it does run again but it looks different than before. Previously it was a smaller window with the white pcsx2 image in the background now it looks newer (v1.7.4452) with the Wayland icon on the window. Maybe it's because of X11 to Wayland things. It does work with that option disabled but it should work by default without having to guess which option to change and I don't know why this problem occurred and whether disabling that option has any downsides.
